# Drop Down Menus and passing the selected value in between views Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, controller, view

I have a drop down menu of all the objects that are part of one model using this code:

```
 <h2>Upload Grades Using "New Grades"</h2>
 <%= collection_select :course, :course_id, Course.all, :id, 
          :name, :prompt => "Select a Course:" %>
 <%= link_to 'New Grade', new_grade_path(:course => :course ) %>
```

In this case my model is Course. How do I access the selection of the user and then pass it to the new.html.erb view. It is to my knowledge that I use the controller to retrieve the value using something like

```
 @course = params[:course][:course_id]
```

Then in my view, I can display the name of the course with

```
 <%= @course.name %>
```

inside of the new.html.erb.

And then, if the course has an association like A course has_many students then I can retrieve and display a list of all the students doing something like

@students = @course.students

But, my thinking here is wrong because my code doesn't work. Can someone point out where I'm going wrong here? I've been at this for hours...

### Update - included config/routes.rb and rake routes

```
    MygradesSr::Application.routes.draw do

    resources :evals

    resources :teams

    resources :categories

    resources :grades

    resources :categories

    resources :tasks

    resources :students

    resources :courses

    post 'grades/upload_grade'

    post 'students/upload_student'

    root :to => "home#index"
    end
```

Rake routes:

```
              evals GET    /evals(.:format)                   evals#index
                    POST   /evals(.:format)                   evals#create
           new_eval GET    /evals/new(.:format)               evals#new
          edit_eval GET    /evals/:id/edit(.:format)          evals#edit
               eval GET    /evals/:id(.:format)               evals#show
                    PUT    /evals/:id(.:format)               evals#update
                    DELETE /evals/:id(.:format)               evals#destroy
              teams GET    /teams(.:format)                   teams#index
                    POST   /teams(.:format)                   teams#create
           new_team GET    /teams/new(.:format)               teams#new
          edit_team GET    /teams/:id/edit(.:format)          teams#edit
               team GET    /teams/:id(.:format)               teams#show
                    PUT    /teams/:id(.:format)               teams#update
                    DELETE /teams/:id(.:format)               teams#destroy
         categories GET    /categories(.:format)              categories#index
                    POST   /categories(.:format)              categories#create
       new_category GET    /categories/new(.:format)          categories#new
      edit_category GET    /categories/:id/edit(.:format)     categories#edit
           category GET    /categories/:id(.:format)          categories#show
                    PUT    /categories/:id(.:format)          categories#update
                    DELETE /categories/:id(.:format)          categories#destroy
             grades GET    /grades(.:format)                  grades#index
                    POST   /grades(.:format)                  grades#create
          new_grade GET    /grades/new(.:format)              grades#new
         edit_grade GET    /grades/:id/edit(.:format)         grades#edit
              grade GET    /grades/:id(.:format)              grades#show
                    PUT    /grades/:id(.:format)              grades#update
                    DELETE /grades/:id(.:format)              grades#destroy
                    GET    /categories(.:format)              categories#index
                    POST   /categories(.:format)              categories#create
                    GET    /categories/new(.:format)          categories#new
                    GET    /categories/:id/edit(.:format)     categories#edit
                    GET    /categories/:id(.:format)          categories#show
                    PUT    /categories/:id(.:format)          categories#update
                    DELETE /categories/:id(.:format)          categories#destroy
              tasks GET    /tasks(.:format)                   tasks#index
                    POST   /tasks(.:format)                   tasks#create
           new_task GET    /tasks/new(.:format)               tasks#new
          edit_task GET    /tasks/:id/edit(.:format)          tasks#edit
               task GET    /tasks/:id(.:format)               tasks#show
                    PUT    /tasks/:id(.:format)               tasks#update
                    DELETE /tasks/:id(.:format)               tasks#destroy
           students GET    /students(.:format)                students#index
                    POST   /students(.:format)                students#create
        new_student GET    /students/new(.:format)            students#new
       edit_student GET    /students/:id/edit(.:format)       students#edit
            student GET    /students/:id(.:format)            students#show
                    PUT    /students/:id(.:format)            students#update
                    DELETE /students/:id(.:format)            students#destroy
            courses GET    /courses(.:format)                 courses#index
                    POST   /courses(.:format)                 courses#create
         new_course GET    /courses/new(.:format)             courses#new
        edit_course GET    /courses/:id/edit(.:format)        courses#edit
             course GET    /courses/:id(.:format)             courses#show
                    PUT    /courses/:id(.:format)             courses#update
                    DELETE /courses/:id(.:format)             courses#destroy
grades_upload_grade POST   /grades/upload_grade(.:format)     grades#upload_grade
students_upload_student POST   /students/upload_student(.:format) students#upload_student
               root        /                                  home#index
```

Comment: @hrr 'undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass'.. I'm getting this for @course.name. so.. The main problem is I don't know if I'm passing the parameter correctly through new_grade_path().

Comment: can u paste routes.rb? and rake routes

Comment: I have added routes.rb and rake routes @hrr

Comment: can you post the params that are sent when clicking your link ? for now, i think your select just sends nothing.

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean @m_x, i believe that my params are being sent with link_to ? And then are being accessed by the controller with params ? Is that wrong convention?

Comment: your link won't magically send the data from the select. This is basic HTML... you have to send this data via GET or POST (url params or a form). just use the debugger or slap a `raise` in your controller, you will be able to see the params that have been sent to your controller.